# Are their any APIs for IBM Bluemix DevOps services like Delivery Pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to use Bluemix DevOps Services from a portal outside of Bluemix. 
Are there APIs which can be used to invoke DevOps services.
For example : How can I create a delivery pipeline without using bluemix or hub.jazz interface?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can make it a lot easier for others to answer your question, if you follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Please make sure to edit your post accordingly, as a lack of quality in a question might result in others not bothering to answer

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered over on IBM's dWAnswers in [this thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/253786/are-their-any-apis-for-ibm-bluemix-devops-services/?smartspace=devops-services).

To put it plainly, no, though you can 'automagically' create pipelines with Bluemix's Deploy to Bluemix feature.